# Can I use LEDs as an augmented reality target?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, led, targeting

I just started programming! I am currently trying to build an augmented reality app using LEDs on IOS platform.
I was wondering if a light (like an LED) can be used as an AR target or can be add as a marker target.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: What I've done once using ARToolKit is to build a transparent cube that was lighted from the inside with LEDs. Then stickered marker patterns around the cube so that the pattern was visible in the dark. That was trackable.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1MneX1SRXZgaBGFHyRUjH2LDqUuQ?e=rVs7Z6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by object tracking a LED light. But tracking of LED light wouldn't work if it will be turn on while tracking, because the light would confuse device camera which would consequently lead to bad tracking experience.

More on how to use object tracking with ARKit, you can find out on this link: 
[Scanning and Detecting 3D Objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects)